# Capturing incoming packets using Wireshark SSL

Tags: tcp, wireshark, packets

A website sends out a BIN file which I like to download. However the website sends it over TCP, and the website is using SSL.

I tried using Herculus to capture the BIN file but without luck.

How can I capture this BIN file? I don't know how to get private keys to decrypt the SSL packets.

Comment: It is unclear what your problem is. Why do you need to use packet capture in the first place and can't simply use the browser to access and download the file?

Comment: @SteffenUllrich To clear it up, I can only visit this specific website from my PlayStation 4 system. The file is being send over TCP to my PS4 system from the PlayStation 4 browser. I want to download this file, but because I cannot access the site from my desktop browser, I need to wireshark the connection somehow to download this file.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> I don't know how to get private keys to decrypt the SSL packets.

You can't unless you hack the server. Private keys are called *private* because they need to be kept private by the server since they are used to proof ownership of the certificate within the TLS handshake.

Apart from that decrypting the traffic using the private key works only with RSA key exchange. But probably most modern system now use ECDHE or DH key exchange where knowledge of the private key is not enough for decryption.

> How can I capture this BIN file?

If you can get access to the URL and the necessary credentials (whatever they are) you can retrieve the file with a browser or some other clients. If you don't have these data then you cannot get the file.

Comment: Okay, so there's basically not a way to get this BIN file. Is this the same story as for getting the page source? I tried spoofing my useragent to visit the site from my PC but it seems they locked that down aswell.

Comment: @Mitch:  This is true for all content which gets transmitted over TLS, no matter of HTML (i.e. "page source") or binary download.

Comment: So Wireshark is not an option anymore. It must be possible to bypass the user agent block. I tried to view my useragent in my browser using `navigator.platform` and it appears it still returns `Win32` instead of `PlayStation 4` which is probably the reason why the site is still blocking me. Do you know if its possible to spoof `navigator.platform`?

Comment: @Mitch: Please don't ask a new question in a comment. Apart from that there are many and easy to find resources on how to spoof the user agent in arbitrary ways with different browsers.

Comment: Managed to spoof the platform using Firefox. Turned out successful, site granted me access. Thanks for your help.

Comment: It’s not true that you need to hack the server to decrypt the SSL packets. If you have access to the client’s SSL Key Log Files you can load those up in Wireshark to decrypt the data: https://wiki.wireshark.org/TLS#tls-decryption

Comment: @Yogarine: please have a look at the question and comments again of the client setup. There is no way to get a SSL key log file in this setup.